# Select a random subset of indices, with minimum consecutive count

Tags: python, numpy, random, indexing

I would like to select a random subset of indices from a numpy array with the caveat that I need each randomly selected index to be part of a consecutive "cluster" of at least three indices in a row.

For example, if I have an array that contains 25 items

```
a = np.arange(0,25)
```

I want to make sure that no index is selected without including at least two neighboring indices. So, for example, if I was looking for a subset of length 12, the following two options both fulfill this.

```
# this has 3 consecutive, followed by 5 consecutive, followed by 4 consecutive
rand_subset_1 = [0,1,2,9,10,11,12,13,18,19,20,21]

# this has 6 consecutive, followed by 3 consecutive, followed by 3 consecutive
rand_subset_2 = [3,4,5,6,7,8,14,15,16,22,23,24]
```

**Attempted Answer**

I tried to figure this out initially by dividing `a` into lists of three.

```
a_mod = np.array([0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],...[21,22,23])
```

and then using `np.random.choice(a_mod, subset_length/3, replace=False)`

However this doesn't solve my problem, for two reasons.

1. I want to be able to input arrays with lengths that don't have to be divisible by three.
2. I don't mind if the subset indices are in cluster sizes that also aren't divisible by three. I just need the cluster to have at least three consecutive indices.

**Clarification Edit:**

Is there a method that allows every number in the subset of indices is part of a "cluster" of consecutive numbers? Ideally this wouldn't limit the cluster to be divisible by a particular integer (which is where I got stuck on my attempted solution above), but would be flexible in allowing clusters to be random lengths with a specified minimum cluster size.

Thanks in advance for any help with this problem!

Comment: It is confusing. So, is what you want select three or more consecutive index at random? Then, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 11] is also what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying question. Yes! That is also completely acceptable as a random subset, but I wouldn't want it to happen on every querty. I'd just like to be able to query the intial array multiple times, for multiple random subsets that are all partially consecutive.

Comment: Do you want each possible acceptable subset to be equally likely, or is a scheme that produces some subsets more often acceptable?

Comment: I don't need every subset to be equally likely. It's okay if it produces some subsets more often, I just don't want it to be limited to subsets of only three.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function. 
It selects an index at random and add two consecutive indices.
After that, select indices without considering the indices selected already.

```
def select_consequtive_index(a, m, n = 3):
    # a: array
    # m: number of index to be selected
    # n: minimum of consequtive counts
    
    output = []
    x = np.random.choice(a)
    if x == 0:
        output += [x, x+1, x+2]
    elif x == a[-1]:
        output += [x-2, x-1, x]
    else:
        output += [x-1, x, x+1]
    
    output += np.random.choice(list(set(a) - set(output)), m - n, replace = False).tolist()
    output = np.array(output)
    output.sort()
    return output
```

code sample.

```
a = np.arange(0, 25)
print(select_consequtive_index(a, m = 12, n = 3))
```

The result is as follows.
[ 3  4  7  8  9 10 11 12 17 21 22 24]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I edited the original question for clarification above. s there a method that allows every number in the subset of indices is part of a "cluster" of consecutive numbers? I do see how this returns at least one cluster of size `n=3` in `output` with 3 consecutive numbers, but I'm looking for a method that allows all numbers in output to be part of a cluster of consecutive indices, and ideally the cluster itself could vary in size, with a minimum size of 3.